# debian: cannot ping beyond the router

Tags: debian, networking, routing, gateway

Hello fellow stackers,

I'm not sure I planned my network configuration in a perfect manner.

I have a home network topography like this:

**modem/router <-> debian router <-> LAN**.

I need to access the Internet from my LAN, behind a debian router.

When I have these 3 rules on the **debian router**, I can access WAN:

```
default via 192.168.0.10 dev enp1s0f1
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp1s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.12 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp1s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.12
```

**`192.168.0.10` is my modem/router**. **`192.168.0.0/24` is the small LAN with the modem/router and a branch of the debian router**. **`10.0.0.0/24` is my private LAN where my Pi is**.

**My problem is that I cannot ping the modem `192.168.0.10` from my workstation `10.0.0.4`, goind through the debian router.**

EDIT: new tryout :

I modified in this way /etc/network/interfaces for the **debian router**:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp1s0f0
iface enp1s0f0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.12
    netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug enp1s0f1
iface enp1s0f1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.12
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.10
```

RESULT: passed networking service validation. It generates these routes on the **debian router**:

```
default via 192.168.0.10 dev enp1s0f1 onlink 
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp1s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.12 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp1s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.12
```

I can ping form the debian router the WAN, DNS ok, ping ok. From my Pi on the 10... network, I cannot ping the modem/router .10 . I can ping the other side interface of the debian router (192.168.0.12).

**On the debian router I have these ufw settings**:

```
*nat

#:PREROUTING ACCEPT - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT - [0:0]

#Port fwd
#-A PREROUTING -i enp1s0f1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.3

# Forward traffic from source through iface
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o enp1s0f1 -j MASQUERADE

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

I don't know why I cannot ping the modem/router from the Rasbian (ping allowed on ufw - don't know if it is meaningful).

`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` is set on the **debian router**.

**iptables -nvL:**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 117K 7348K ACCEPT     all  --  enp1s0f0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**iptables -t nat -nvL:**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**On the Rasbian I have theses routes (simplified)**:

```
default via 10.0.0.12 { the debian router's directly connected iface }
10.0.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.12
```

**So, any clues why I can't ping the modem from the Raspbian Pi? :-)**

Comment: You could add more than one default route if you give them different metrics; eg. `ip route add default ... metric 1` .. `metric 2`. Don't know if this helps you with your actual problem, though.

Comment: Christopher, these 3 routes work as expected on both Raspbian and Debian. The single problem I have is that the DEFAULT route is not persisted. The two other routes were actually auto generated by config (meaning there can be at least two as-you-call-them-default-routes, unless debian doesn't know what it is doing itself).

Comment: using one own's IP as gateway will tell the system that there's actually no gateway and the whole internet is available (usually creating ARP requests for *any* IP). The only place where this is fine is when using a device doing proxy ARP (some 3G/4G devices)

Comment: note if it wasn't clear: gateway = default route, the one used with ip route add default ... (where you're using one, not 3)

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't understand correctly, I'm not into net. I wonder how this config worked for days... now I have a valid /etc/network/interfaces config with one gateway,  which is the modem/router. I update the question.

Comment: @mosvy you can't usefully have two default routes. If you have two with different metrics then the one with the lower metric is the default route and the other is a no-op.

Comment: @roaima how's that not useful? if you pull the plug, you still have internet via the wireless interface. It's the default with NetworkManager&co to create multiple default routes with different metrics. Anyways, I haven't had time to research OP's problem, but as a side-rant: both `ifupdown` and `NetworkManager` are badly broken, and doing _anything_ "special" (like ipv6 prefix delegation) is a nightmare on desktop linux -- I always have to do custom stuff to make it work. This is in stark contrast to eg. OpenWRT, where almost everything works out of the box.

Comment: hi, does anyone has a clue why I can't ping the modem/router from inner LAN please?

Comment: @mosvy that scenario has nothing to do with the configuration described here.

Comment: @roaima what's the configuration descibed here? ;-) to the OP: it would help if you told what error you get from `ping`: "cannot ping" is too broad. Also, it's not at all clear (at least for me) that your router is actually configured to do forwarding (`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`?)

Comment: Have those firewall rules actually been applied (specifically what's the output of `iptables -nvL; iptables -t nat -nvL` please).

Comment: I was going to write an answer and then realised there's a pretty good walk through of setting up a Linux router on the redhat website.  The steps listed also work on Debian: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html

Comment: @roaima the ping looses all packets, none returns. Ping is not filtered on the debian router.

Comment: for routing I use ufw config as showed in the original thread, I set: -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o enp1s0f1 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: I've just been going back over your question. It's not very clear to me which snippets relate to which machine. Could you [edit] your question, please, to identify which parts are on your modem/router (if any), which parts are on your Debian router, and which parts are on your Pi. Thanks.

Comment: @roaima ok, I have updated the question. Moreover, I replaced the Pi with a laptop, where I have a strange problem, maybe it is valuable info: on this laptop on 10.0... LAN the interface can't get an IP address (dhcp on, when the Pi had static ip) - it shows where the net icon is, a circle icon. Maybe that's interesting.

Comment: @PhilipCouling thank you for your link, it is valuable. I already use NAT through ufw, you can find  the Masquerade instruction in the question. I've gone through this redhat procedure, nothing new.

Comment: @roaima I added what you asked about iptables -nvL. I must admit I don't clearly understand iptables...

Comment: I've amended my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `iptables` output is from the Debian router, your firewall `MASQUERADE` rule hasn't been applied. (In fact, none of your rules has been applied.)

To fix the problem you can do one of two things

1. Apply the firewall rules using the appropriate `ufw` command (I don't use `ufw`) so that your entire 10.0.0.0/24 network is hidden behind the single externally-facing IP address of your Debian router

OR

2. Create a static route on the modem/router that declares it can reach your internal 10.0.0.0/24 network via 192.168.0.12. Otherwise its default route, pointing upstream, will be the only place it will know to send such packets.

Comment: thank you. Your answer lighted a bulb, I found the problem, see my answer. I'm sorry to have wasted your time for such a stupid error. Ty very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I must have forgotten to set

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

into /etc/default/ufw.

As @roaima pointed out, there were no ACCEPT rules prior to FORWARD ACCEPT. Now, everything works as expected :-)

Comment: IF the `iptables` output you gave us was indeed from the Debian router, the policies were already set to `ACCEPT`. What you were missing is the `MASQUERADE` or the static route just as I desctibed in my answer. That UFW may have changed the default firewall policiy is then a corrollary that you have addressed in your answer here.